# why v86 stuck at "Fetching v86.wasm ..."?

Tags: qemu, react-os

I am trying to run React OS on v86 but it stuck I. see the Js console and it Says:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: c.setOption is not a function                  v86_all.js:374
    at new kf (v86_all.js:374:88)
    at mf (v86_all.js:385:67)
    at v86_all.js:379:376
```

I tried to re-download the v86.wasm but no fix

Answer (score 0):

Well on this date, their example image of Reactos is not working even for me. However, try building one / try https://copy.sh/v86/. At the end of this page use setup.